# Function that creates a dictionary for words in a file

Tags: file, function, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm trying to create a function that for every word in a specific file it adds a new key to the dictionary and as its value it adds a list of every word that comes after that word.
My code is not working for some reason I can't figure out. Here it is:

```
def mimica(input_file):
    d = {}
    f = open(input_file)
    w = f.read().split()
    f.close()
    a = len(w)
    for i in range(0, a):
        word = []
        b = i + 1
        for a in range(b, a):
            word.append(w[a])
        d[w[i]] = word
    return d
```

this is what my file has:

```
Car yellow and fast
Toy black and fun
Person tall and nice
```

and this is the output of my function:

```
{'and': [], 'Toy': ['black', 'and', 'fun'], 'Car': ['yellow', 'and', 'fast', 'Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 'fast': ['Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person'], 'Person': [], 'black': ['and'], 'yellow': ['and', 'fast', 'Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and'], 'fun': [], 'tall': [], 'nice': []}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for a in range(b, a):
```

You're overwriting the previous value of `a` with this loop. Try changing the name to something else.

```
    for x in range(b, a):
        word.append(w[x])
```

Result:

```
{
    'Car': ['yellow', 'and', 'fast', 'Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'yellow': ['and', 'fast', 'Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'fast': ['Toy', 'black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'Toy': ['black', 'and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'black': ['and', 'fun', 'Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'fun': ['Person', 'tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'Person': ['tall', 'and', 'nice'], 
    'tall': ['and', 'nice'], 
    'and': ['nice'], 
    'nice': []
}
```

(whitespace added by me for clarity)

Comment: Is it correct that `"and"` is not followed only by `"nice"`? After all, it appears earlier and is then followed by many words.

Comment: @tobias_k, that's a possible interpretation of the problem statement. If so, the OP could put `if w[i] in d: continue` at the beginning of the loop, in order to prevent later instances of a word from overwriting earlier instances.